# How to create object model that updates when one of its member's updates

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I would like to create a model for a nested object, where updating a deeply nested property bubbles up to the parent object. The overall type looks something like this, but with more nesting:

**TLDR: It seems like there should be a way to define the Container and List of Members both as providers, but I'm struggling with the syntax to do so.**

I have two classes, **Container** and **Member**
Each are set up to be Notifier Providers

```
class Container {
  late String type;
  late String name;
  late List<Member> members;
  late int id;

  Container(this.type, this.name, this.members, this.id);
}

extension MutableContainer on Container {
  Container addMember({
    required String memberType,
    required String memberName,
    required int memberId,
  }) {
    final newMembers = [...members, Member(type, name, id)];
    return Container(type, name, newMembers, id);
  }
}

class ContainerNotifier extends StateNotifier<Container> {
  ContainerNotifier(Container newContainer) : super(Container("", "", [], 0));
}

final containerProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<ContainerNotifier, Container>((ref) {
  final members = ref.read(memberListProvider);
  return ContainerNotifier(Container("", "", members, 0));
});
```

```
class Member {
  late String type;
  late String name;
  late int id;

  Member(this.type, this.name, this.id);
}

extension MutableMember on Member {
  Member updateName({required String newName}) {
    return Member(type, newName, id);
  }
}

class MemberListNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<Member>> {
  MemberListNotifier(List<Member> newMembers)
      : super(newMembers
            .map((Member member) => Member(
                  member.type,
                  member.name,
                  member.id,
                ))
            .toList());

  void updateMemberName(int memberId, String newName) {
    final List<Member> newMembers = state;
    state = newMembers
        .map((Member member) => member.id == memberId
            ? member.updateName(newName: newName)
            : member)
        .toList();
  }

  void setMembers() {
    state = [
      Member("one", "one", 1),
      Member("two", "two", 2),
      Member("three", "three", 3),
    ];
  }
}

final memberListProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<MemberListNotifier, List<Member>>((ref) {
  return MemberListNotifier([]);
});
```

Then in the UI I have a button to set the state of the list and then a button for each member of the list to update the name of the list item.

```
class Home extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final containerRef = ref.watch(containerProvider);
    final buttons = containerRef.members;
    final members = ref.watch(memberListProvider);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Container")),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  ref.read(memberListProvider.notifier).setMembers();
                },
                child: const Text("set members")),
            ...buttons
                .map((Member button) => ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          maximumSize: const Size(200, 50),
                          minimumSize: const Size(200, 50)),
                      onPressed: () {
                        ref
                            .read(containerProvider.notifier)
                            .updateMemberName(button.id, "four");
                      },
                      child: Text(button.name),
                    ))
                .toList()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I click the button to `setMembers`, the memberRef updates, but the containerRef does not.

It seems like there should be a way to define the Container and List of Members both as providers, but I'm struggling with the syntax to do so.

Please don't suggest a different framework (like getIt or BLoC) since I'm using this project to specifically learn to use Riverpod.

Comment: Have you check the family attribute of riverpod providers, you want to have a container per city right? or did I misunderstood something? also maybe check freezed package (same author) it lets you copy your model and change only some attributes you want

Comment: You can ignore the city, it was added to show that there are more fields in Container than just "Days". I left out a few fields for simplicity. I'm not sure that Families will work well since the argument I would be passing to the notifier would be a list of objects. I may end up with the same problem where the reference to the list of objects doesn't change so the parent won't change.
Freezed may save a few lines of code, but ultimately I would prefer to have notifiers all the way down, so that when an item at the bottom of the nested object changes, the parent is notified.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand what you want to accomplish with wraping all members with a container object but you can fix your error by doing 2 things:

1. Container should be a Provider only, no reason to use a StateNotifierProvider, you want to change state of the list, and that is in another provider
2. use `ref.watch` instead of read so the containerProvider updates itself.

---

```
final containerProvider = Provider<Container>((ref) {
    final members = ref.watch(membersListProvider); /// This will update the provider
    return ContainerNotifier(Container("", "", members, 0));
});


class Home extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final containerRef = ref.watch(containerProvider);
    final buttons = containerRef.members;
    final members = ref.watch(memberListProvider);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Container")),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  ref.read(memberListProvider.notifier).setMembers();
                },
                child: const Text("set members")),
            ...buttons
                .map((Member button) => ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          maximumSize: const Size(200, 50),
                          minimumSize: const Size(200, 50)),
                      onPressed: () {
                        ref
                            .read(memberListProvider.notifier)
                            .updateMemberName(button.id, "four");
                      },
                      child: Text(button.name),
                    ))
                .toList()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```